# Portainer doesn't show icons anymore since upgrading to v2 (Traefik Proxy)

Tags: traefik, portainer

Since upgrading to Portainer v2, the icons would suddenly not load anymore. I can still access Portainer (which is proxied by Traefik), but after a bit of testing, I noticed, only `/` would be forwarded. If a path was given, Traefik would throw a 404 error. This is a problem because Portainer loads the fonts from eg. `/b15db15f746f29ffa02638cb455b8ec0.woff2`.

There is one issue about this on Github, but I don't really know what to do with that information: https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/3706

My Traefik configuration

```yaml
version: "2"

# Manage domain access to services
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=acme.json
      # Enable/Disable staging by commenting/uncommenting the next line
      # - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --global.sendAnonymousUsage
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
      # - ./acme-staging.json:/acme.json
    environment:
      CF_API_EMAIL: ${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
      CF_API_KEY: ${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik_auth
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal

      # Declaring the user list
      #
      # Note: all dollar signs in the hash need to be doubled for escaping.
      # To create user:password pair, it's possible to use this command:
      # echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - traefik.http.middlewares.traefik_auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_USERS}

      # Standard middleware for other containers to use
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https_perm.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https_perm.redirectscheme.permanent=true

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
```

And my Portainer configuration

```yaml
version: "2"

# Manage docker containers
services:
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data/:/data/
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000

      - traefik.http.routers.portainer0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer0.rule=Host(`${PORTAINER_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`${PORTAINER_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=le

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
```

**What do I have to change to make Traefik be able to forward the paths so that Portainer can load the icons?**

Answer (score 0):

Could you try flush your DNS Cache?
In Chrome 'chrome://net-internals/#dns' into URL bar and pressed enter.
Then click on 'Clear host cache'
Then refresh your portainer page

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is also an Alpine version of Portainer.

After switching to that (`image: portainer/portainer-ce:alpine`), the icons seem to be working again. I don't know what the issue is with the regular image, but this solves it for now.

PS: I had tried to use the Access-Control header on Traefik, but that didn't help. I guess it's a problem with Portainer's code itself.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing this issue, I resolved this by deleting my Browser Cache or just do a full Refresh with CTRL+Shift+R